# Why is Elokim plural?

Tags: hebrew, shemos-sacred-names

There are many names of G-d and all of them seem to be written in a singular form. But Elokim is the only name I know that has an "-im" termination. What is the meaning behind this?

Comment: http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/b-hebrew/2002-January/012341.html

Comment: Are you asking why any name of God would be in the plural, or why other names of God are not in the plural?

Comment: hahah, why not both?